# Frequently linked-to site ripping off Magento Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I noticed that a user on this site frequently links to a site called Birdshost, and I was curious, so I checked it out.

Right at the top of the page, you can see this:

[image: Birdshost banner]

This is a clear misappropriation of Stack Exchange assets.

It also looks like the site rips off Stack Exchange's framework almost exactly, albeit with a slightly modified design.

Some questions are reposted on this page too:

Compare the MageSE:
[How to overcome timezone problem in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5938/how-to-overcome-timezone-problem-in-magento)

With the Birdshost Variant: http://qa.birdshost.com/?qa=115/how-to-overcome-timezone-problem-in-magento

Is this something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of Q&A sites out there built on similar principles as StackExchange. most probably, the one you mentioned is just one of them.

I cleaned up all the references to that website from the answers. In case I missed some, please flag them or feel free to edit them and remove the link.

The account of the user that was posting these links is temporary suspended for excessive self promotion.

Thanks for spotting this.