# Blatant ripoff site scraping Magento StackExchange

Tags: discussion

Has anyone seen this site?  http://answermagento.com/

I know this subject has been briefly discussed but this isn't another site using a StackExchange-clone platform.  This site consists entirely of scraped content from Magento SE.

[Frequently linked-to site ripping off Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/frequently-linked-to-site-ripping-off-magento-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The content is CC share-alike, but this site isn't properly crediting the origin.

Not important though because the domain name infringes our mark. I've sent a note to our legal team to C&D the owner.

Comment: someones about to get #shrek'd.

Comment: Looks like it worked because they are down.

Comment: Intellectual Property Rights #FTW

Answer (score 6):

Thats a common problem with stackoverflow/stackexchange content. Usually you dont find it on google anymore, as the duplicate content restrictions are good enough to recognize them.

If you still see such things, you can report them to the StackExchange Team via one of the communication ways.

I for example sent a mail 3 Years ago about one case. It took some days, but they answered and forwarded the case. They have dedicated persons for this kind of Issue.

So, just report it directly to StackExchange, they will forward it to the person responsible for this.

Answer (score 2):

**Meet "Alan Storm"**
[image: Alan Storm]

This is another website ripping Magento SE, compare this:

- Ours: [Inline translate Chrome Bug?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/6435/3326)
- Theirs: http://worldofcoder.com/question/12459/how-to-inline-translate-chrome-bug.html

They left out the poster's names and replaced the pics, hence the good looking "Alan Storm"... ;)